# Python Gensim word2vec vocabulary key

Tags: python, unicode, gensim, word2vec

I want to make word2vec with gensim. I heard that vocabulary corpus should be unicode so I converted it to unicode.

```
# -*- encoding:utf-8 -*-
# !/usr/bin/env python
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import pprint

with open('parsed_data.txt', 'r') as f:
    corpus = map(unicode, f.read().split('\n'))

model = Word2Vec(size=128, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
model.build_vocab(corpus,keep_raw_vocab=False)
model.train(corpus)
model.save('w2v')

pprint.pprint(model.most_similar(u'너'))
```

Above is my source code. It seems like work well. However there are problem with vocabulary key. I want to make korean word2vec which use unicode. For example word `사과` which means apology in english and it's unicode is `\xC0AC\xACFC` If I try to find `사과` in word2vec, key error occur...
Instead of `\xc0ac\xacfc` `\xc0ac` and `\xacfc` stores separately. 
What's the reason and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word2Vec requires text examples that are broken into word-tokens. It appears you are simply providing strings to Word2Vec, so when it iterates over them, it will only be seeing single-characters as words.

Does Korean use spaces to delimit words? If so, break your texts by spaces before handing the list-of-words as a text example to Word2Vec.

If not, you'll need to use some external word-tokenizer (not part of gensim) before passing your sentences to Word2Vec.

Comment: Umm... I give input as `[u'\ud504\ub791\uc2a4', u'\uc758', u'\uc138\uacc4', u'\uc801', u'\uc774', u'\u11ab', u'\uc758\uc0c1', u'\ub514\uc790\uc774\ub108', u'\uc5e0\ub9c8\ub204\uc5d8', u'\uc6c5\uac00\ub85c', u'\uac00', u'\uc2e4\ub0b4', u'\uc7a5\uc2dd', u'\uc6a9', u'\uc9c1\ubb3c', u'\ub514\uc790\uc774\ub108', u'\ub85c', u'\ub098\uc11c', u'\uc5c8', u'\ub2e4']
`. List of unicode strings. Isn't it valid?

Comment: That's not what your code for creating the `corpus`  list shows. (Is your actual code different from what's in the question?) What is corpus[0]? If it's a string, rather than a list-of-tokens, then all Word2Vec sees will be individual characters. (And, recent versions of gensim will log a warning if your entire vocabulary seems to be single-character tokens.)