# word2vec models consist of characters instead of words

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I am trying to make a word2vec model by Gensim on Persian language which has "space" as the character delimiter, I use python 3.5. The problem that I encounter was I gave a text file as input and it returns a model which only consists of each character separately instead of words. I also gave the input as a list of words which is recommended on :

[Python Gensim word2vec vocabulary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065843/python-gensim-word2vec-vocabulary-key])

It doesn't work for me and I think it doesn't consider sequence of words in a sentence so it wouldn't be correct.

I did some preprocessing on my input which consist of:

collapse multiple whitespaces into a single one
tokenize by splitting on whitespace
remove words less than 3 characters long
remove stop words

I gave the text to word2vec which gave me result correctly, but I need it on python so my choice is limited to use Gensim.

Also I tried to load the model which made by word2vec source on gensim I get error so I need create the word2vec model by Gensim.

my code is:

```
  wfile = open('aggregate.txt','r')    
  wfileRead = wfile.read()    
  model = word2vec.Word2Vec(wfileRead , size=100)   
  model.save('Word2Vec.txt')
```

Comment: You tagged your question with `character-encoding`, yet you seem to be unaware of how to deal with it. I highly recommend you explicitly specify the encoding of "aggregate.py" when you open it, instead of relying on your environment's default encoding. It might well be that the default is (by chance) the correct choice and that your problem has nothing to do with encoding, but it's one of the first things to rule out here.

Comment: @lenz thanks for your reply, yes I check the encoding. the "aggregate.txt" file encoding is "utf-8" which is the defult encoding of python 3.5. It's not the problem which in that case I would get encoding error and it won't give me a charater based model.

Comment: When opening files for reading/writing, the default encoding is not necessarily UTF-8. It depends on your OS configuration (eg. on a Unix system, it depends on the environment variable `LC_ALL`), and you can check what it is with `locale.getpreferredencoding()`.

Comment: In any case, since you know your file is encoded with UTF-8, you should really `open()` it with `encoding='utf-8'`. This makes sure the file will be interpreted properly even if the script is run somewhere else.

Comment: @lenz I did that too, but it doesn't change the result!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gensim Word2Vec model does not expect *strings* as its text examples (sentences), but *lists-of-tokens*. Thus, it's up to your code to tokenize your text, before passing it to Word2Vec.

Your code as shown just passes raw data from 'aggregate.txt' file into Word2Vec as `wFileRead`.

Look at examples in the gensim documentation, including the `LineSentence` class included with gensim, for ideas

Answer (score 2):

You need to tokenize your text to words using `nltk`.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize

tokenized_text = word_tokenize(wfileRead)
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(tokenized_text  , size=100)
```